# I can't auth from client using ldap when user's password is enctypted by {SHA} {SSHA},when it is {CRYPT} work

Tags: ldap, openldap

Server: Centos 7.2, Client: Debian 8.6

Problem is that i cannot log on client when password is encrypted by SHA/SSHA on server side.

Ldapsearch from client station work. I can recived  attrs from server when i ask server as user raj3.It work with SSHA i CRPYPT encoded user password.

On server side  password was generaded by

ldappasswd -s password123 -W -D "cn=admin,dc=pydio,dc=sum,dc=edu,dc=pl" -x "uid=raj3,ou=People,dc=pydio,dc=xxx,dc=edu,dc=pl"

Command:

`getent passwd raj3`

resonding well from client.

What more when i have password encoded by SHA/SSHA  i can login on user raj3 via  JXpolorer(from windows in the same network)  to ldap server   and i can
 see attrs  of this user.

New details 02.09.2019:

On client side there are :
ibpam-ldap and  instalation was prepared by :

```
aptitude -y  install libnss-ldap libpam-ldap ldap-utils
```

*/etc/pam.d/common-password*

```
password        [success=2 default=ignore]      pam_unix.so obscure
password        [success=1 user_unknown=ignore default=die]     pam_ldap.so try_first_pass
password        requisite                       pam_deny.so
password        required                        pam_permit.so
```

I was testing above with sha512  in line:

```
password        [success=2 default=ignore]      pam_unix.so obscure sha512
```

and the same problem too.

*/etc/nsswitch.conf*

```
passwd:         compat ldap
group:          compat ldap
shadow:         compat ldap
gshadow:        files

hosts:          files myhostname mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns
networks:       files
protocols:      db files
services:       db files
ethers:         db files
rpc:            db files
netgroup:       ldap
```

*/etc/pam_ldap.conf*

```
pam_password crypt
```

---

getent passwd raj3   -work on client only on root local account on other local acount no.

For me is misunderstood why  CRYPT work but SSHA no when  command  getent no work on non root acount.

ACL
olcAccess: {0}to * by dn="cn=admin,dc=pydio,dc=sum,dc=edu,dc=pl" write by  self write by users read by * auth

Does ACL is wrong to forbid anonymouse user so see tree of ldap ?  But why i can log with CRYPT enrypted password with such ACL?  IT is to hard solve it by me.

Answer (score 0):

I am just guessing because so little information is provided here.

Do you have pam ldap installed and properly configured? It seems that nss ldap is installed and configured however that is only half of what you need here.

EDIT: you seem to have multiple basic issues and not one. Thus I would suggest to read this howto to get started http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/archived/LDAP-Implementation-HOWTO/pamnss.html
This is an old and tried docs. It should help you to get this working.

Comment: I have add new detials to main ticket.

Comment: Getent on client  machnie work only on  root account  but on non-root local account no work .

Answer (score 0):

I found  when "problem  with {SSHA} i {CRYPT}" apear itself:

I had wrong admin password in /etc/pam_ldap.secret. Ok it was my mistake. 
Mystery is : Why   user  with  password crypted by CRYPT could auth / user password crypted by SSHA can't  when  password in /etc/pam_ldap.secret is bad ?.
It is make headache.